# Get width of specific div and use as another div's height?

Tags: javascript, jquery, get, height, offsetwidth

I have two div's. #divA & #divB.

#divA has a width of 100% and I want to get the px value of the div and apply it to #divB as it's height CSS. I've tried using .offsetWidth but to no avail. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Have you tried $("#divB").height($("#divA").width()); ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use .css('width') to keep units intact (ex: 400px), use .width() to get just the numerical value (ex: 400) for use in mathematical computations.

for what you're doing:

```
var divAWidth = $('#divA').css('width');
$('#divB').css('height', divAWidth);
```

if you're getting mathematical:

```
var divAWidthNumber = $('#divA').width();
var halfThatWidth = divAWidthNumber / 2;
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you! I have it working, just wondering if it's possible to implement to a style sheet rather than a page?

Comment: If you mean assign the width to the height via CSS instead of JavaScript i would say no, but I'm sure somebody smarter may chime in and school us both. :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use jQuery:

```
var getwidth = document.getElementById("div1").style.width;
document.getElementById("div").style.height = getWidth;
```

With jQuery

```
var getwidth = $("#div1").width();
```

EDIT

```
$("#div").height(getwidth);
```

Comment: Why 30? Why did you assign 30 instead of getWidth?

Comment: It's just an example. Anything can be used. I suppose that `getwidth` would be better...

Comment: Especially taking into account that you have calculated it. Also, you can do it with a one-liner: $("#div").height($("#div1").width());