# HTML/js How can I set multiple div widths from multiple different image widths?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to add my own captions to my images which are the same width as the images. I'm using javascript to obtain the widths of the images, from [Get width of specific div and use as another div's height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21057702/get-width-of-specific-div-and-use-as-another-divs-height), except that only works for an individual image, and would require me to set a separate id for each div. Is there an easier way?

The image captions are created by

```
<img src="myimage.png">
<div class="imgtxt">Caption</div>

<img src="myimage2.png"> <!-- Width set to 80% -->
<div class="imgtxt">Caption2</div> <!-- Div width still at 100% because its the width of the image class -->
```

and the current javascript is taken from the link above

```
var imgWidth = $('img').css('width');
$('.imgtxt').css('width', imgWidth);
```

Comment: Is the caption always immediately after the image?

Comment: I'd wrap the pair of images and captions in, say, a `figure` tag and use jQuery to loop over them via `$('figure').each(function() { $('figcaption', this).width($('img', this).width()) } );` See this codepen: https://codepen.io/csdv/pen/RBzvyp

Comment: You should consider making this more semantic : http://html5doctor.com/the-figure-figcaption-elements/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$("img").each(function(i){
  var imgWidth = $('img').eq(i).css('width');
  $('.imgtxt').eq(i).css('height', imgWidth);
});
```

Comment: If I had an image without a caption, what do you suggest? I've found that my captioned images at the bottom of the page end up being the same width of the images further up the page which don't have captions, rather than the images it is attached to

Comment: You can add id to divs, and id should be a number that correspond to image.
The code would be:

$("img").each(function(i){
var idp="#" + i;
var imgWidth = $('img').eq(i).css('width');
$(idp).css('height', imgWidth);
});

I think that should work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('img').each(function() {
    imgWidth = $(this).css('width');
    $(this).next('.imgtxt').css('height', imgWidth);
});
```

**Ps:** *jQuery*'s `.css` method doesn't return a *jQuery object* so it doesn't offer implicit collection iteration, so we need to explicitly iterate through the collection using *jQuery*'s `.each` method.

Answer (score 1):

Optionally, you could grab all the captions, and navigate from them to the image to get the width to set.

```js
$('.imgtxt').width(function(){
  return $(this).prev('img').css('width');
});
```

```css
img:nth-of-type(1) {
  min-width: 50px;
  min-height: 25px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

img:nth-of-type(2) {
  min-width: 100px;
  min-height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.imgtxt {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="myimage.png">
<div class="imgtxt">Caption</div>

<img src="myimage2.png">
<div class="imgtxt">Caption2</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want a solution without javascript, you could try adding a wrapper to your images and captions like this

```
<div class="img-wrapper" style="display: table">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x300">
  <div class="imgtxt">Caption</div>
</div>
```

And then styling the wrapper as a table. I've demonstrated an example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/thwm0ouq/7/).

Comment: Please include all relevant code in  the answer itself. Without the CSS you only have a half answer. Top tip, in the editor use the `<>` button to bring up a snippets editor, this gives you something very similar to jsFiddle in StackOverflow itself. P.S. I didn't down vote.

Comment: You could also make this mare semantic with `figure` and `figcaption`. See: http://html5doctor.com/the-figure-figcaption-elements/

Comment: Sorry about that, by saying "styling the wrapper as a table" I just meant to add `display: table;` to the css for it. I've added it to my answer for clarification